# Symfony2.4 fosUserBundle lastlogin and remember_me does not work

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm usign FosUserBundle in my symfony 2.4 application

Everything works fine except2 things :

- last_username is alway null
- IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED is always
  false (But the cookie is created correctly)

My twig template is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
            {{ 'layout.logged_in_as'|trans({'%username%': app.user.username}, 'FOSUserBundle') }} |
            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
                {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
            </a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">{{ 'layout.login'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="flash-{{ type }}">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

    <div>
        {% block fos_user_content %}
        {% endblock fos_user_content %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Security.yml

```
    main:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: false
        provider:  main
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            remember_me: true
        logout:
            path:   fos_user_security_logout
            target: /login
        remember_me:
            key: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 31536000
            path: /
            domain: ~
```

routing.xml

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
     http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

     <route id="fos_user_security_login" pattern="/login">
         <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:login</default>
      </route>
```

Any ideas ?